# Creating matrices using a Do-loop

Tags: matrix, homework, iterators

Here is an image of current assignment; I am not able to do step 6 to 8

[image: I am not able to do step 6 to 8]

When I try to do the Do-loop, it states that the `{i, j}` does not have appropriate bounds.

This is what I did for step 6:

```
Do[i + j = figueroaMat[[i, j]], {i > j}, {i, 0, 9}, {j, 0, 9}]
```

My question is about how to do step 6 to step 8.

Comment: Please do not post images of your work, especially when the images display at a size that make them difficult to read. Please post your actual Mathematica code in the form of text that can be copied and pasted into a Mathematica notebook. Without such, it will be difficult to reproduce your problem and to experiment with possible solutions.

Comment: Step 1: IdentityMatrix[10] Step 2: IdentityMatrix[10] // MatrixForm Step 3: figueroaMat = IdentityMatrix[10] Step 4: figueroaMat[[1, 1]]
figueroaMat[[9, 9]]
figueroaMat[[4, 5]] Step 5: when I executed step 4, my outputs were 1,1 and 0. Step 5 states that figueroaMat[[i,j]] repsent the (i,j) entry of the matrix figueroaMat

Comment: Step 6: By using the Do loop, assign i+j to (i,j) entry of figueroaMat if i>j. Then execute figueroaMat//Matrix form. Do[i + j = figueroaMat[[i, j]], {i > j}]
figueroaMat // MatrixForm                                                                    
Step 7: By using the Do loop, assign 0 to (i,j) entry of figueroaMat if i=j. Then execute figueroaMat//Matrix form. Do[0 = figueroaMat[[i, j]], {i = j}]
figueroaMat // MatrixForm

Comment: Step 8: By using the Do loop, assign i-j to (i,j) entry of figueroaMat if i<j. Then execute figueroaMat//Matrix form.Do[figueroaMat[[i, j]] = i - j, {i < j}]
figueroaMat // MatrixForm

Comment: Alternative: `SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; i < j :> i + j, {i_, i_} :>  0, {i_, j_} /; i > j :> i - j}, {10, 10}] // MatrixForm`.  You could also use `Table` to generate the array instead of using `IdentityMatrix` merely to pre-allocate an array that you then overwrite with a `Do[]` loop.

Comment: When I do the SparseArray as you stated, it does work and i get the correct answer, but the homework is asking to use Do loop specifically. I try to use the input of sparse array with the Do loop, but it did not work.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is homework, I won't give a complete solution, but here is a strong hint on how to proceed.

Step 6 is done by testing for `i > j` with `If` at each iteration of the loop. Also, `figueroaMat` must on the lefthand side of the assignment experssion. Like so:

```
 If[i > j, figueroaMat[[i, j]] = i + j]
```

For 7 and 8, just change the test.

Comment: Can I use Do[] instead of If[]? When I do If[] the way that you stated, I get a matrix 1[0,-1,-2,-3,-4, so on, which is not correct. I tried to do Do[i > j, figueroaMat[[i, j]] = i + j] =. The output tells me that the expression j cannot be used as a part of specification and Do: non-list iterator figueroaMatt[i,j]=i+j at position 2 does not evaluate to a real numeric value.

Comment: In your Do loop replace `i + j = figueroaMat[[i, j]], {i > j}` by `If[i > j, figueroaMat[[i, j]] = i + j]`  and index, i.e, i and j should start from 1